# Extract hour of the day from a timestamp in Big Query SQL ('FROM' error)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to extract the hour of the day from the created_at timestamp (line 3) in the second column via Big Query SQL. With my current code I get the error: "Encountered " "FROM" "FROM "" at line 3, column 18. Was expecting: ")" ..."

Current code:

```
 SELECT 
    date(created_at) as date,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM created_at) AS hour,
    sum(net_revenue) as net_revenue, 
    count(order_unique_id) as orders  
    FROM [source]
    WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), -2, 'DAY')) AND CURRENT_DATE()
    GROUP BY 1,2
```

Thanks in advance for helping!

Comment: `as orders,  ` -- You have extra comma here.

Answer (score 0):

The only error I see in your query is in the `WHERE` clause.  Presumably you intend:

```
WHERE DATE(created_at) BETWEEN DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL -2 DAY') AND CURRENT_DATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see from your example, `created_at` column is not `DATE` data type.

While, `EXTRACT(part FROM date_expression)` function requires date data type as argument (https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#extract)

So, you have to construct date like you do in second line:

```
SELECT 
    date(created_at) as date,
    EXTRACT(HOUR FROM DATE(created_at)) AS hour,
...
```